# Accidentally disabled network on azure vm

Tags: azure, network

I was troubleshooting some network issues on my VM ,so by mistake I disabled network .
Now ,i'm not able to connect my machine via rdp .Tried changing the size of vm but still no good .

So kindly help me with the solution !